# Warm voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

Why is my voltage regulator get warm while my car is not running "68 corvette" battery is also going dead, is it the regulator or another problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Theory

Generically,

warm = power flowing through

very warm = a lot of power flowing through

batteries provide power over time (energy)

therefore...

dead battery.

### Application

Sounds like something is drawing current when your car is "not running".

Might be a partial short somewhere, an accessory (radio, CB, entry lights, trunk mounted amplifier, etc), or failing switch/relay/linkage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's probably the regulator itself. It works by controlling the field current into the alternator in order to regulate the alternator's output voltage that is charging the battery. It sounds like it has not "recognized" that the engine isn't running (I don't know the details of how it does that) and is dumping battery current into the alternator anyway in an attempt to increase the voltage.

Either the regulator itself has failed, or some wiring between the regulator and the ignition switch has failed in some way.